# code : 5001 message : "An internal error has occurred." name : "Internal Error" when calling getAccessTokenAsync

Tags: outlook, office-js

`code:5001
message:"An internal error has occurred."
name:"Internal Error"`

I get this error when I call getAccessTokenAsync in my outlook addin. In desktop version I get a another error with `code:13003`. With the AttachemntDemo sample I get the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using an on-premises Exchange Server with a local Domain Account.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins#13003):

> #### 13003
>
> User Type not supported. The user isn't signed into Office with a valid Microsoft Account or Work or School account. This may happen if Office runs with an on-premises domain account, for example. Your code should ask the user to sign in to Office.

Also confirm that your server meets these requirements:

> If the user is connected to Office 365 or Outlook.com, mail server requirements are all taken care of already. However, for users connected to on-premises installations of Exchange Server, the following requirements apply.+
>
> 1. The server must be Exchange 2013 or later.
> 2. Exchange Web Services (EWS) must be enabled and must be exposed to the internet. Many add-ins require EWS to function properly.
> 3. The server must have a valid authentication certificate in order for the server to issue valid identity tokens. New installations of Exchange server include a default authentication certificate. For more information, see [Digital certificates and encryption in Exchange 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351044(v=exchg.160).aspx) and [`Set-AuthConfig`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj215766(v=exchg.160).aspx).
> 4. In order to access add-ins from the Office Store, the client access servers must be able to communicate with https://store.office.com.

---

:

Comment: Yeah, after giving administrator permissions problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspect the network traffic and see the actual request - there is more information about the error as this function is just a wrapper around the network request and does not give enough information.

I was receiving the same error and when checked the network request - discovered that I have to add one more application as a Pre-authorized application.